# PHP match *.domain.com

Tags: php, preg-match

This is some code from a php file im working with. I need to match 'domain.com' but when I enter that it's not working because it's parsing a document looking for href tags and i think it needs the http://www. for the match. I tried the below preg match but it didn't work and my coding isn't to great any help would be appreciated.

preg_match ("/domain.com/i");

```
        $match = 'http://www.domain.com'; 

        for($i=0;$i<$documentLinks->length;$i++) 
        {
            $documentLink = $documentLinks->item($i);
            if ($documentLink->hasAttribute('href') AND substr(strtolower($documentLink->getAttribute('href')), 0, strlen($match)) == $match) 
            {
```

Comment: is it just me or is the dommain (instead of domain) mistype your problem?

Comment: Mistype here only (edited) but that's not the problem it's fine in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
for($i=0;$i<$documentLinks->length;$i++) 
{
    $documentLink = $documentLinks->item($i);
    if ($documentLink->hasAttribute('href')) 
    {
        if (preg_match('!^https?://([^/]+\.)?domain\.com(/|#|$|\?)!i', trim($documentLink->getAttribute('href'))))
        {
```

the regexp is the important part:

```
^https?://([^/]+\.)?domain\.com(/|#|$|\?)
```

start at the beginning of the string, match http or https, then an optional subdomain that may not include forward slashes (so you know you're still in the domain part), followed by the domain you want to match, then either the start of a path, start of a fragment or the end of the url

Comment: +1, I like it, and a nice sensible regex. One minor addition I would make - `trim()` the value before the match. Because you have used start/end markers (as you probably should here), any leading/trailing whitespace will cause a non-match. A lot of browsers will forgive this, so you probably should as well. Also, does your regex account for query strings?

Comment: both good points - query string could come directly after the domain part. fixing both...

Comment: Thanks, it's matching domain.com, www.domain.com but not test.domain.com why would that be?